# Shortening the syntax {var1, var2} /. # & /@ list

Tags: syntax, replacement

I noticed that I often turn out to have a list of substitutions in the form

```
list = 
{
  {var1 -> value1, var2 -> value2, ..., varn -> valuen}, 
  {var1 -> value1, var2 -> value2, ..., varn ->  valuen}
}
```

and need to extract some of the values (for instance for plotting).
I use the syntax

```
{var1, var2} /. # & /@ list
```

Is there a shorter one?

Comment: @PinguinDirk I disagree with your reasoning. `Function` has very low precedence and everything before `&` will be "inside" `Function`. The `FullForm` is `Hold[Map[Function[ReplaceAll[List[var1,var2],Slot[1]]],list]]`. But still your solution is correct :P

Comment: oh, right, let's delete that comment (as it is too late to edit) and just keep the idea: `{var1, var2} /. list`. Thank you sir for pointing that out!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it only applies to the poster's local situation and needs.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thank you

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't know how to reformulate the question as to make it more easily found by related searches. If you have any idea, please feel free to edit the title or content

Comment: @m_goldberg The behavior of Mathematica here (in the answer) is a sensible extension of the behavior of expressions "of the form"  `_/.{__Rule}` and `_/.{__?(MatchQ[#,_Rule]&)}`. Both those forms have examples in the docs, but the form provided by the OP does not. How the behavior extends cannot be seen from the docs and it may be confusing, so I am in favor of keeping the question open.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm in favor of keeping it open as up until quite recently, I was using the `Map` form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, remove the `Map` entirely. For example,

```
{a, b} /. {{a -> q, b -> r}, {a -> s, b -> t}}
(* {{q, r}, {s, t}} *)
```